# How to draw a setting once in python?

Tags: python, psychopy

I code an experiment regarding visual short-term memory. I want to draw 8 squares once (4left/4right). I coded a loop and psychopy draws 8 squares every frame, but I only want 8 squares during one trial. How do I get rid of this?

```
def drawLearn():


    for i in range(len(squaresLeft)):
        while True:
        squaresLeft[i].pos = (xL(),y())
        validPosition = True
        for j in range(i): 
            if overlaps(squaresLeft[i], squaresLeft[j]):
                validPosition = False
        if validPosition:
            break

for i in range(len(squaresRight)):
    while True:
        squaresRight[i].pos = (xR(),y())
        validPosition = True
        for j in range(i): 
            if overlaps(squaresRight[i], squaresRight[j]):
                validPosition = False
        if validPosition:
            break


    Sqr1.draw ()
    Sqr2.draw ()
    Sqr3.draw ()
    Sqr4.draw ()
    Sqr5.draw ()
    Sqr6.draw ()
    Sqr7.draw ()
    Sqr8.draw ()
```

Part of Real Trial:

```
while True:    
if Timer.getTime() >= startLearn and Timer.getTime() <= startLearn +  timeLearn.
    drawLearn()

if len( event.getKeys(['q']) ) > 0:
    break

Wind.flip()


Wind.close()
```

Thank you for your help

Update: I want to test 320 trials and every trial consists of 8 squares drawn. Atm the main problem is, that 8 squares are drawn per frame while RealTrial-Loop but I want them drawn once during the drawLearn function.

Comment: Could you update the question to be more clear? What should you present during the subsequent trials? To only draw once, just run the code once instead of in a loop...

Comment: Did it. Is it more understandable now? :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code draws all the squares and flips the window. You are getting what you are coding. Maybe what you want to do is draw once and put the `getKeys` in the timing loop? For instance,

```
drawLearn()
Wind.flip()
while True:    
if Timer.getTime() >= startLearn and Timer.getTime() <= startLearn +  timeLearn.
    if len( event.getKeys(['q']) ) > 0:
        break
```